# Exact view position on top of ImageView - android

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an interactable imageView by setting some invisible image buttons on top of it, the user can then click different parts of the image and do things with it, the problem is that i need this image buttons to be in very exact positions in relation to the image view, if the phone size varies even a little, the image buttons will get off the positon i want them to be.

The xml where the image view is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".fragments.Offroad18nitro4wdbuggy_frontFragment">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="OffRoad 1/8 nitro 4WD buggy front" /> <!-- Here just to show the programmer which fragment is showing -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLosi4_offroad18nitro4wdbuggy_front"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/losi4_18scale_front"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibTest"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:background="@color/colorGreen"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see in the second screenshot, the image button is out of place, my phone is the Samsung Galaxy S6.

[Screenshot of the image button in the exact position i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX0t3.png)

[Screenshot of the app being emulated to my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARsAK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've dealt with this exact problem before.  The workaround that I managed to accomplish is to divide the screen up into several sub-layouts so it looks like a grid of layouts.  First divide the screen in half at the center point, then place an empty textview with no dimensions in the center of the top and bottom layouts, which will allow you to divide those layouts into four.  Then do the same thing for those four to create sixteen if you have to.  Then place your image buttons along the sides or the attached to the center point of whichever of these layouts contains your desired area.

The point is to create a grid that is fixed relative to the center of the screen.  That way, if the screen size changes, the grid and the buttons attached to it will adjust accordingly.  Its not a perfect solution but it worked for my purposes.  Here is a link to a sample xml file from the project that I used this strategy in:

https://github.com/ribalding/AdventureAdventure/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_kitchen.xml

Comment: Actually, i tweaked around a little more for a few hours and now it works, for every screen size. Thanks a lot ! :D